# How to fix conflicting boot files in a dual boot system?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a dual boot system where I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my primary hard drive and windows 10 on the secondary drive. Both are 64 bit. I used to have Windows 7 32 bit. Every time I try to boot from grub(2) I get an error saying that the boot file could not be found. I have no problems booting from BIOS (except when I enter BIOS from grub. Then I get the same error).

The file not found is: /Windows/System32/winload.exe

BootInfo summary:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12326949/

I would greatly appreciate a step by step explanation.
Thank you!